# Godror and query with panic error: expected 0 arguments, got 1

Tags: go

This code has raised panic error, with message "sql: expected 0 arguments, got 1" when executed:

```
row:= db.QueryRow(`SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE 1=?`, 1)
err := row.Scan(&test)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

go version go1.17.5 darwin/amd64

godror version: v0.30.0

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
row:= db.QueryRow(`SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL WHERE 1=:1`, 1)
err := row.Scan(&test)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Oracle uses :1, :2, ... and not "?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).